# How do I resolve No qualifying bean for dependency using Java config

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I get the following stack trace trying to republish to my WildFly server from eclipse Spring Tool Suite:

```
12:50:21,451 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dbAppConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in VFS resource ["/Users/tim.daley/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/StaffVacation.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/cru/staffvacation/spring/jpa/service/PersonService.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository.PersonRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in VFS resource ["/Users/tim.daley/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/StaffVacation.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/cru/staffvacation/spring/jpa/service/PersonService.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository.PersonRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository.PersonRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 48 more
```

My web.xml is as follows, although by goal is to minimize it or eliminate it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>StaffVacation</display-name>

    <!-- 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>org.cru.staffvacation.spring</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     -->

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

AppInitializer.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.config.MvcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);       
        applicationContext.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
        applicationContext.scan("org.cru.staffvacation.spring");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

DbAppConfig.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.AppInitializer;
import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.service.PersonService;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=AppInitializer.class)
public class DbAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter //implements TransactionManagementConfigurer
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbAppConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB");
        datasource.setUsername("root");
        datasource.setPassword("");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactoryBean(DataSource datasource)
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(datasource);
        factory.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() 
    {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ph = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ph.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ph;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.cru.staffvacation.spring");
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.error(entityManagerFactory.getObject().getClass().getName());
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    /**
     * Since the LocalSessionFactoryBean is available on the context, the LocalSessionFactoryBean.getObject will supply
     * the session factory by the auto detection of spring.
     *
     * @param factory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

MvcConfiguration.java:

```
    package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"org.cru.staffvacation.spring"})
@EnableWebMvc //<mvc:annotation-driven />
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

    private String name;
    public String getName() {return this.name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    private String country;
    public String getCountry() {return this.country;}
    public void setCountry(String country) {this.country = country;}

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "{id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", country=" + this.country + "}";
    }
}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository;

import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.domain.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>
{
    public Person findById(Long id);
}
```

PersonService.java

```
package org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.domain.Person;
import org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonService.class);

    @Autowired
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;}

    public PersonService(PersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public Person getPersonById(Long id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        return this.personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for(Person p : personsList){
            logger.info("Person List::"+p);
        }
        return personsList;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }

    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(p);
        logger.info("Person updated successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }

    public void removePerson(Long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, id);
        if(null != p){
            session.delete(p);
        }
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details="+p);
    }
}
```

WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is the homepage!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that if I move all the classes into the org.cru.staffvacation.config package, everything works just fine.

Comment: Now if anyone can help me fix the Not Found from http://localhost:8080/StaffVacation/ ------ PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/StaffVacation/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=PersonService.class)
```

This looks for repositories in the package of PersonService, i.e. `org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.service`. But your repository is in the package `org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository`.

Comment: That just backs up the problem 1 level. Now I get Error creating bean with name 'dbAppConfig'. dbAppConfig -> personService -> PersonRepository. No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.cru.staffvacation.spring.jpa.repository.PersonRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: dbAppConfig -> personService -> PersonRepository is just the chain of failed bean creations.

Comment: Actually, it looks like using basePackageClasses=AppInitializer.class solves the problem. I'd have thought that @ComponentScan(basePackages={"org.cru.staffvacation.spring"})
 on MvcConfiguration would have done the trick, but apparently that doesn't apply to JPA.